# Crear dataFrame (pandas) desde diccionario con indice en el diccionario

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy intentado generar un dataframe desde un diccionario:

```
agenda = {'id': [1,2,3], 'nombre' : ['Miguel','Carlos','Pedro'], 'edad' : [12,13,19]}
```

y en el diccionario ya viene agregado el id que se debe de utilizar en el dataframe.
Al crear el dataframe solo consigo lo que se muestra en la imagen con el siguiente código

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(alumnos, columns =['id', 'nombre', 'edad'])<br>
display(df_student)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podría solo tener como índice del dataFrame la columna id?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer que la columna `id` sea el índice, solo debes indicar en el dataframe que los índices sea la columna `id` haciendo una simple asignación.

```py
frame = pd.DataFrame(agenda, columns =['id', 'nombre', 'edad'])

frame.index = frame.id #hacemos la asignación
#si quieres conservar la columna id comenta la siguiente línea
frame.drop("id", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Si solo quieres que los valores sean los índices, entonces solo debes hacer:

```py
frame = pd.DataFrame(agenda, columns =['id', 'nombre', 'edad'], index=agenda["id"])
```